# Aligning content to center with toggle sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have recently used a code for toggle sidebar I found on stackoverflow. However one of the biggest issues is aligning content to center while the sidebar is toggled. I cannot get any of my content in the #B div to arrange to the middle when it is toggled on or off. Here is my JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/4054/

Now, what I have done is odd.
For #B, I have given it the following properties

```
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Simple enough right? but it doesn't center the ".center" div like ti should. What it does instead is make it to where the page scrolls (to the right). The issue in this is that the page is being told to be 100% + 200px wide. Now If I use a calc(100%-200px) it will work, but it will not center out the div. What's going on here?

I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way, but I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following..

CSS:

```
.center {
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}

#B{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Update JSFiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/4056/)

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/4055/) will align the center div.

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: - 50% of div width;
```

Answer (score 0):

I still not know what you expecting
I hope this what you want...

```js
$('button').toggle(
    

function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '0');
}, 
    function() {
        var size = $(window).width();
    var centerdoc = size/2;
    $('#B').css('left', centerdoc);
}
)
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#A, #B {
    position: absolute;
}
#A {
    top: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:orange;
}
#B {
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:green;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.center {
width: 30px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"><button>toggle</button>
    
    <div class="center">
        TEST
    </div>

</div>
```

just run the snippet code.